# How to get ControllerManager in Unit Test in ZF2

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2

I wish to inject some dependencies into a controller before running dispatch in a unit test.

The controller is like

```
class WidgetController {
   private $foo;
   public function setFoo ($foo) { $this->foo = $foo; };
   public function barAction () { return array('foo' => $this->foo);  };
}
```

The test is like

```
class WidgetControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase {
    function testBarAction ()
    {
       // ERROR HERE - does not get controller, error can't get ControllerManager
       $controller = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()
            ->get("ControllerManager")
            ->get("MyApp\Controller\WidgetController");


       $controller->setFoo("my injected value");
       $this->dispatch("/my-app/widget/bar");
       $this->assertTrue(
          stristr("my injected value", 
                  $this->getResponse()->getBody()));
    }
}
```

I am not sure how i could set the value of `WidgetController::$foo` before running dispatch;

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the config in the ApplicationServiceManager, you could try:

```
$applicationServiceLocator = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
$config = $applicationServiceLocator->get('config');
$config['controllers']['factories']['MyApp\Controller\WidgetController'] = function ($sm) {
    $controller = new \MyApp\Controller\WidgetController();
    // ... do initialization logic
    return $controller;
};
$applicationServiceLocator->setService('config', $config);
```